# How to create a scope for a has_many relationship in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `Group` model that has many `Events`, and I am trying to find the groups which have public events only via something like `Group.public_events`

Here is my Group:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And here is my Event:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I would like to make a `scope :public_events` to find `.where(private: false)` on Event, but should this go on the Group or Event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will go in the Event like this.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  scope :public_events, -> { where(private: false) }
end
```

Comment: Do you call it as Group.first.public_events?  Because I get a noMethodError.  Thx

Comment: You can call it as `Group.public_events`

Comment: call it as Group.public_events

Answer (score 3):

you can put in Event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  scope :public_events, lambda { where('private = ?',false)}
end
```

and you can call it

```
@public_events = Group.first.events.public_events
```

Comment: If I do that, I get a undefined method error.  What am I doing wrong?  Thx

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to mention .events, I just corrected above @public_events = Group.first.events.public_events

Answer (score 1):

You can use do this.

```
scope :public_events, ->(parameter_if_any) {
  where({ private: parameter_if_any||false } )
}
```